# строки в JS не получается преобразовать

Tags: javascript

Не понимаю в чем моя ошибка, совсем новичок

Пишу функцию:

```
function multiply(first, second) {
    return parseInt(first)  * parseInt(second) 
};
```

Привожу результат к строке - 3 результата получаются правильными из 14) ошибка такого типа + expected - actual - '1.9240045408977038e+34' + '19240045408977038918943543720037256'

Comment: а ошибка то в чем?

Comment: Тут нет ошибок, но возможно, вам надо привести результат обратно к строке. По крайней мере в комментариях ответ дан как строки `-> '1'`.

Comment: `function multiply(a, b) { return "" + a*b }`

Comment: @Alex  Привожу результат к строке - 3 результата получаются правильными из 14) ошибка такого типа + expected - actual - '1.9240045408977038e+34' + '19240045408977038918943543720037256'

Comment: @optimus Привожу результат к строке - 3 результата получаются правильными из 14) 
ошибка такого типа + expected - actual 
- '1.9240045408977038e+34' + '19240045408977038918943543720037256'

Comment: @ТатьянаИванова первые цифры же правильные... но JS не умеет такие большие числа показывать)

Comment: Если автор задания подразумевал именно такое решение, то мне жаль и автора, и учащихся, и будущих работодателей.

Comment: @ТатьянаИванова JavaScript не умеет точно показывать настолько большие числа. Даже если их вывести на печать, они будут с ошибкой, поскольку значащими являются только 16 знаков. Можете проверить `parseInt("19240045408977038918943543720037256").toPrecision(35)` - все цифры после определенного знака будут неправильные.

Comment: @ТатьянаИванова для больших чисел нужно писать определенные алгоритмы, которые называются "длинная арифметика", к примеру: https://habr.com/ru/post/354930/. Но если вы действительно новичок и не слышали о работе с большими числами, то последняя проверка явно не для вас. Решение может быть такое: `function multiply(first, second) { return "" + BigInt(first)  * BigInt(second) };`

Comment: @Alex большое спасибо, все работает! Хотелось бы узнать, что в данном случае означают " "  в return

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так (если поддерживается, конечно)

```
function multiply(first, second) {
  return BigInt(first) * BigInt(second) + ""
}
```

Comment: большое спасибо, подскажите, для чего нужны пустые " "?

Comment: @ТатьянаИванова, чтобы строка получилась.